# Date and If function together

Tags: excel

Thank you for your time!

I want Excel to determine the date on multiple conditions.

If the given date in A1 is 29-Nov-1980 and one of the conditions is 30-Jun-2016 then the date should result to 29-Nov-2014. Please refer to the table below for more conditions.

```
Date of joining  As of this year  Condition 1 
27-Jun-05        27-Jun-15        30-Sep-15 
02-Jul-05        02-Jul-15        30-Sep-15 
10-Sep-05        10-Sep-13        30-Sep-15 
01-Dec-05        01-Dec-13        30-Sep-15 
15-Jul-06        15-Jul-14        30-Sep-15 
07-Aug-06        07-Aug-14        30-Sep-15
```

The table above is the actual solution that I am looking for. I have huge data and have to process every month. The second condition deals with Odd and Even years.

Please help me in this if possible.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you better explain the logic? *"If the given date in A1 is 29-Nov-1980 and one of the conditions is 30-Jun-2016 then the date should result to 29-Nov-2014"*: I don't see what the relationship is between those dates, and how you get the result from the first two. Please explain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sure

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sure I would try to explain my best. Basically, Any even year in A1 shall result in a current even year. For. Ex if A1 is 29-Nov-1980 and since its an even year, its corresponding value in this year should be 29-Nov-2016 but if the date and month fall after 30-Jun-2016 then the corresponding value should be 29-Nov-2014. Hope this explanation helps!

Comment: Please refer to the table for more examples and variations

Comment: Is the table correct for the line `10-Sep-05`?  According to the logic the result should be `10-Sep-15`, not `10-Sep-13`. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In this case, condition falls in Sep, therefore, the cutoff is taken as 31-Aug-2015 hence the resulting year is 2013 instead of 2015. I know it's complicated to explain.

Comment: So if the cut-off is taken as `31-Aug-2015`, then why not put that as condition, as that *really* is the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this formula:

```
=IF(EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2))>C2,
    EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2)-24),
    EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2)))
```

It may look complicated, but there is a lot of repetition in it. Each part explained:

```
TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2)
```

This takes the difference of year between the condition date and the date of joining. Then it is divided by 2 to get the the number of 2-years that can fit between the two years. Lets call this **YearDiff** to facilitate the explanation. Then we have:

```
EDATE(A2,24*YearDiff)
```

This adds that number of 2-years (24-months) to the joining date. This could be the desired result, but there is a possibility that it overruns the condition date. Lets call this **Result1**. That is where the last part comes in:

```
IF(Result1 > C2, subtract 2 years from Result1, Result1)
```

It should look like this (but replace the `;` with `,`):

[image]

It might be that after having entered the formula in the B cells, you get to see numbers, not dates. In that case, just apply the Date format to them.

#### Remark about the meaning of the condition

In comments you explained that the result `10-Sept-2015` is not correct when the condition is `30-Sept-2015`, because the cut-off date is `31-Aug-2015`. This seems unnecessary complex: in that case put the cut-off date in the condition. It is strange to put a date that is one month later as "condition". If still you want to keep it in that way, then change the formula to this (`>C2` is replaced with `>=DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2),1)`):

```
=IF(EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2))>=DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2),1),
    EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2)-24),
    EDATE(A2,24*TRUNC((YEAR(C2)-YEAR(A2))/2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Apparently I am getting an error. Is the date in A2 in some specific format? Kindly advise

Comment: It is a separator issue (I am in Europe). Replace all the `;` with `,` in the formula. I updated my answer accordingly. NB: The format in A2 is not important as long as it is a date.

Comment: I also added a paragraph about how you want the condition to influence the result.